# Why is jersey causing process error messages when sending an http get request

Tags: api, http, kotlin

I'm trying to confirm that the get request is sent successfuly with a simple response of "It Works!" but I keep getting error message from Jersey api which is not specific

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
```

```
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException: null for uri: http://localhost:8080/sso/customconfigs
```

This is my code:

```
@Path("http://localhost:8080/sso/customconfigs")
@NoAuthRequired

class SSOCustomConfigsResource {
@GET
  fun sendConfigs(): Response {
    return Response.ok("It Works!").build()
  }
}
```

This is what I get when sending the request

```
{
    "identifier": 70004,
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "The path '/sso/customconfigs' is not available.",
    "type": "NotFoundException"
}
```

I get the same error when trying to send requests  to other endpoints.

Comment: `@Path("/sso/customconfigs")`

Comment: Also tried that but it didn't work, Basically the issue was in my route configuration and I fixed it. Thanks